# Get list just of visitor posts / shared events etc

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have a public Facebook page for our dance group. Friends and strangers will post to our Timeline (sharing events etc) – you can see them all under Visitor's Posts, which opens in a modal on the page.

I want to be able to pull  all Visitor's posts with the graph api.

The Visitor's posts are not included in the basic `{page-id}/feed` request, so i cannot filter for them post-retrieval.

I have tried the `{page-id}/tagged/` Edge, but for some reason this excludes certain posts.

Graph request with page ID `93039009689/tagged/`

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/391224331052795?method=GET&path=93039009689%2Ftagged%2F&version=v2.5

Compare to Visitors Posts feed here: https://www.facebook.com/contactinsydney/posts_to_page/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph Explorer with the User access token should not retrieve all visitors posts. Did you try with the **Page access token**? It worked for me.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes with the user Page Access Token it seems to work (ie because I am  logged in user, with Editor permissions on our page, I have full access to the 'tagged' Edge and can make that query to get these posts. The problem is, what I am trying to do is get the tagged posts using my App, which is obviously not a logged in 'user' with editor privileges on our page. I am wanting to get these visitor posts and display them on a separate webpage to encourage community engagement. Is this possible – to give an app an Editor for a page, therefore can request a Page Access token?

Comment: Ciao @spacewindow. Try selecting your own app from the dropdown menu on the top-right corner of the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and get the Page Access Token. 

You should be able to retrieve all _/tagged_ posts exactly the way you do using the Graph API even though I am not sure you can actually give _roles_ to an App.